# Swift: how can I create external interface for static library (public headers analog in Objective-C .h)

Tags: swift

I need to create a static library with Swift,
and I need to know how can I implement interface for the library.

In Objective-C I can mark needed headers as public in **build phases**,
but there is not any headers and any interfaces in Swift.

What should I do with Swift?

Comment: Or in other words: When Apple releases Cocoa Touch written natively in Swift, how will they prevent me from seeing their implementation source code?

Comment: Here is a Build Phase script you could use.
https://gist.github.com/brennanMKE/ad8f68524aac6877ef1f277a820d335d

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply put: you don't.

Swift is not a language that separates headers and implementations. When you create a library or framework based on Swift and only for consumption by Swift, the Xcode default build setting of `DEFINES_MODULE` already does the job for you. This will create a `.swiftmodule` file, which will be used by `import` in other Swift projects.

If you want your code to be importable from Objective-C though, you might want to check if the `SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER` build setting is also enabled (which it is by default for frameworks as far as I know). Then the Swift compiler will generate a `<ProductName>-Swift.h` file for you, which you can import in Objective-C code to access your Swift classes and functions.

Comment: Did this change with XCode beta 5? I can't find a .swiftmodule file anywhere in my project (Cocoa Touch Library with Swift)

Comment: Is there a way to have Xcode generate a <FileName>-Swift.h file for each swift file or object, instead of one file with all of them lumped together?

Answer (score 7):

If you want your `Swift` framework to expose certain classes to the interface, simply mark the 'entities' (functions, variables etc.) `public`:

```
public class Class {}
public var variable: Int
public func function() { }
```

By default, all entities have `internal` access.

- `public` entities are intended for use as API, and can be accessed by any file that imports the module, e.g. as a framework used in several of your projects.
- `internal` entities are available to the entire module that includes the definition (e.g. an app or framework target).
- `private` entities are available only from within the source file where they are defined.

Source: [the official Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=5).