# How do I declare a public interface, such as apple does. Another way, hide the implementation

Tags: init, swift

Just like UILabel class:

```
class UILabel : UIView, NSCoding {

    var text: String! // default is nil
    var font: UIFont! // default is nil (system font 17 plain)
    var textColor: UIColor! // default is nil (text draws black)
    var shadowColor: UIColor! // default is nil (no shadow)
    var shadowOffset: CGSize // default is CGSizeMake(0, -1) -- a top shadow
....
}
```

But if I define a class like this, which  didn't has init function also. The compiler will warning me.
How could I do the same thing as Apple does, to hide the implemention, only declare the interface. Thanks.

Comment: "how could I hide my implementation" that is a good question. "How do I ship a Swift library without source code?" Where do the "headers" to compile against come from? No idea.

Comment: I may get the solution, just do it like java's interface or protocol. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: how can I create external interface for static library (public headers analog in Objective-C .h)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070722/swift-how-can-i-create-external-interface-for-static-library-public-headers-an)

Answer (score 2):

UILabel is not implemented in Swift.

What you see here is derived from the Objective-C header file for UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a closer look at protocols. You can declare your protocol like this:

```
protocol UIViewProtocol {
    var text: String { get }
    ...
}
```

and reference it later in your class:

```
class MyClass : UIViewProtocol {
    ....
}
```

Reference by Apple: [iOS 8 Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_345)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the class name and try.

```
class MyClass : UIView, NSCoding {

        var text: String! // default is nil
        var font: UIFont! // default is nil (system font 17 plain)
        var textColor: UIColor! // default is nil (text draws black)
        var shadowColor: UIColor! // default is nil (no shadow)
        var shadowOffset: CGSize // default is CGSizeMake(0, -1) -- a top shadow
        }
```