# How do I add a swift class to my framework header?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

In Xcode 6 (beta 4 6A267n), I added a Framework (selecting Swift as the language) and the framework header has this comment:
// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import

Through SO I found that you have to append "-Swift" to your header file name, however I was not able to get this to work.

I've also added $(SRCROOT) to my header search path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to create your own Swift library? In which case, you do not need to create an external interface as described here:

[Swift: how can I create external interface for static library (public headers analog in Objective-C .h)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070722/swift-how-can-i-create-external-interface-for-static-library-public-headers-an)

With Swift you identify your public interface by marking classes and methods as `public`.

The header that has the `-Swift` suffix is a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) and is what you use to bridge Objective-C code so that it can be used in your Swift application.

Comment: I have a "successfull" import statement at the top of my ViewController.swift file (no error), but when I try to use a class I get "Use of undeclared type" -- I can see the class "Jump to Definition" on the imported framework.

Comment: I am facing same issue but above is not solve my problem, Can you explain more on that?

Comment: Any solutions Found??

Comment: Did you mark the class as public? Also keep in mind that the implicit init() is not public and you may need to explicitly define a public init().